# What does int() function with 2 args do in Python

Tags: python, int

In the following code what does int() do with these 2 arguments:

```
if (i=='0X0F'):
    stat = int(log[i+1],16)
```

Comment: How do you think it would differ from the docs?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because googling "python int" is not too difficult.

Comment: @MattDMo That's not a reason to close the question, just to downvote.

Comment: @John I know, but still...

Comment: This seems fairly straight-forward to Google, or just try with an interpreter. Was there something you thought it did or should do that you found counter-intuitive? Sometimes it helps to let folks know that you thought about something a bit and just where your confusion lies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second argument tells `int` the base of the input string. From the help:

```
class int(object)
 |  int(x=0) -> integer
 |  int(x, base=10) -> integer
 |  
 |  Convert a number or string to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments
 |  are given.  If x is a number, return x.__int__().  For floating point
 |  numbers, this truncates towards zero.
 |  
 |  If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string,
 |  bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in the
 |  given base.  The literal can be preceded by '+' or '-' and be surrounded
 |  by whitespace.  The base defaults to 10.  Valid bases are 0 and 2-36.
 |  Base 0 means to interpret the base from the string as an integer literal.
```

So if you do `int(S, B)`, it says convert `S`, which is the string representation of a number in base `B`:

```
In [63]: int('10', 2)
Out[63]: 2

In [64]: int('10', 3)
Out[64]: 3
```

Now, if `B` is larger than 10, then python assumes that the next sequence of digits comes from `ABCD...`. Thus:

```
In [65]: int("A", 11)
Out[65]: 10
```

Answer (score 11):

```
class int(object)
 |  int(x=0) -> int or long
 |  int(x, base=10) -> int or long
 |  
 |  Convert a number or string to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments
 |  are given.  If x is floating point, the conversion truncates towards zero.
 |  If x is outside the integer range, the function returns a long instead.
 |  
 |  If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string or
 |  Unicode object representing an integer literal in the given base.  The
 |  literal can be preceded by '+' or '-' and be surrounded by whitespace.
 |  The base defaults to 10.  Valid bases are 0 and 2-36.  Base 0 means to
 |  interpret the base from the string as an integer literal.
```